# React Native Switch on Android report an error

Tags: javascript, android, switch-statement, react-native

I use a Switch on Android in RN 0.21.0:

```
 <Switch
          onValueChange={(value) => this.setState({trueSwitchIsOn: value})}           
          value={this.state.trueSwitchIsOn} />
```

It showes an error:

```
(standard input):43372:03-03 09:32:02.096 E/unknown:React(11609): Exception in native call from JS
(standard input):43373:03-03 09:32:02.096 E/unknown:React(11609): java.lang.NullPointerException
(standard input):43374:03-03 09:32:02.096 E/unknown:React(11609):   at android.text.StaticLayout.<init>(StaticLayout.java:58)
(standard input):43375:03-03 09:32:02.096 E/unknown:React(11609):   at android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat.makeLayout(SwitchCompat.java:606)
(standard input):43376:03-03 09:32:02.096 E/unknown:React(11609):   at android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat.onMeasure(SwitchCompat.java:526)
(standard input):43377:03-03 09:32:02.096 E/unknown:React(11609):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16529)
(standard input):43378:03-03 09:32:02.096 E/unknown:React(11609):   at com.facebook.react.views.switchview.ReactSwitchManager$ReactSwitchShadowNode.measure(ReactSwitchManager.java:56)
(standard input):43379:03-03 09:32:02.096 E/unknown:React(11609):   at com.facebook.csslayout.CSSNode.measure(CSSNode.java:137)
(standard input):43380:03-03 09:32:02.096 E/unknown:React(11609):   at com.facebook.csslayout.LayoutEngine.layoutNodeImpl(LayoutEngine.java:294)
(standard input):43381:03-03 09:32:02.096 E/unknown:React(11609):   at com.facebook.csslayout.LayoutEngine.layoutNode(LayoutEngine.java:210)
(standard input):43382:03-03 09:32:02.096 E/unknown:React(11609):   at com.facebook.csslayout.LayoutEngine.layoutNodeImpl(LayoutEngine.java:492)
(standard input):43383:03-03 09:32:02.096 E/unknown:React(11609):   at com.facebook.csslayout.LayoutEngine.layoutNode(LayoutEngine.java:210)
(standard input):43384:03-03 09:32:02.096 E/unknown:React(11609):   at com.facebook.csslayout.LayoutEngine.layoutNodeImpl(LayoutEngine.java:492)
```

So I guess it the measure error and set a size :

```
  <Switch
              onValueChange={(value) => this.setState({trueSwitchIsOn: value})}
              style={{width:100, height:40, backgroundColor:'#a03'}}
              value={this.state.trueSwitchIsOn} />
```

then the error goes away and a blank area showes without the **Switch ** View.

Answer (score 1):

I also had met the problem like yours，and don't know how to fix it, I use the npm install react-native-material-switch to replace the official switch .

Comment: I wrote my own 'Switch' component in JS.